# Round corners inside StackView not displaying correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, interface-builder

I have a simple StackView with equal spacing in my interface builder:

[image]

When I run the app the position and size of the buttons are correct (exactly as shown in interface builder) but when I try to round the corners of the button in the middle with the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: button.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft,.bottomRight],
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    shape.path = maskPath.cgPath
    button.layer.mask = shape

}
```

I get an incorrect result (button's text is not longer centered nor covering the full wide):

[image]

Where is the problem? Thanks

Comment: did you try to see what is covering this view? you can inspect views in runtime, add a screenshot please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not be using `button.bounds` in the `viewDidLoad()` as the geometry of your view isn't set at this point. Try moving your code to `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` where the bounds will be correct.

Answer (score 2):

If the first answer still doesn't solve your problem, wrap your code in this `DispatchQueue.main.async {}` in the `viewWillAppear` or `didAppear`.